# DB2 SQL regular expression with "or" operator

Tags: sql, regex, db2

Why on earth is this regular expression not working!?!?!?

```
create table SAMPLE (STR char(3));    
insert into SAMPLE values ('aaa');
insert into SAMPLE values ('bbb');
insert into SAMPLE values ('ccc');

select 
    STR
    , xmlquery('fn:matches($STR,"a")') as A
    , xmlquery('fn:matches($STR,"b")') as B
    , xmlquery('fn:matches($STR,"a|b")') as A_OR_B
from SAMPLE;
```

Results in:

```
STR;   A;     B;     A_OR_B
'aaa'; true;  false; false
'bbb'; false; true;  false
'ccc'; false; false; false
```

`A_OR_B` is always false, even when `A` or `B` is true.

PS: I'm using DB2 10

Comment: You are missing two commas, but everything else seems to be correct.

Comment: @Marcos: If after fixing the commas it still does not work, you might try with `xmlquery('fn:matches($COL_NAME,"(a)|(b)")') as A_OR_B` (it was an example on IBM site, no idea if that will change anything).

Comment: post an answer @stribizhev points is points

Comment: @maraca: Commas corrected. Thanks

Comment: @dan1111: Added some sample data

Comment: @dan1111: Then I must be having a nightmare because that same example doesn't work in my compute. I have edited the question to actually add the code that generates the sample data above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the *character encoding*. E.g. if the `|` is not really a `|`, but something that looks the same or similar, let's say `¦`. In that case the regex tries to match `a¦b` literally instead of `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a dodgy work around by making multiple calls to RegExp and combine them with the `or` operator.

```
select 
    xmlquery('fn:matches($COL_NAME,"a")') as A
    , xmlquery('fn:matches($COL_NAME,"b")') as B
    , xmlquery('fn:matches($COL_NAME,"a|b")') as A_OR_B_Error
    , xmlquery('fn:matches($COL_NAME,"a") or fn:matches($COL_NAME,"b")') as A_OR_B
from MYTABLE
```

Comment: What you could try: 1. escape the `$` --> `\$` 2. Use two single quotes `''` instead of double quotes 3. Could there be a problem with character encoding, so that `|` becomes something else like `¦`?

Comment: @maraca: It was actually a problem with the character encoding. I did though that the vertical pipe looked funny, but assumed it was a font issue... Anyway, thank you very much. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it and give you the points.

Comment: Ok thanks, glad I could help, I tried to write a high quality answer, but it's not easy ;-)